# HTML Service Submit Form not calling google.script.run function

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a script that used to work just fine, but has suddenly stopped working.

The user selects an option from a user-created menu, which launches a dialog box (HTML Service form) to collect two parameters. This is all working fine.

When the users submits the form, this code should execute.

```js
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" onclick =
"google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close())
.createAgenda(this.parentNode)"/>
```

The form is closing (`google.script.host.close()` works), but the `createAgenda` function is not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for `withSuccessHandler()` (and `withFailureHandler()`) is supposed to be a callback function. You've provided something that isn't a function: `google.script.host.close()`. Since you've included the parentheses, `close()` gets executed first, to obtain a return value for `withSuccessHandler()`. That closes the dialog, and halts the client-side JavaScript.

You just need to remove the parentheses, referring to the function by name only:

```js
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" 
 onclick="google.script.run
                       .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                       .createAgenda(this.parentNode)"/>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks :)  It's odd that it has been working for a year and suddenly stopped, but it's fixed now.