# HTML Dialog in Google Sheets google.script.run. fails to run Apps Script function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets for remote gaming with an elderly friend (with the game publisher's permission).

I am trying to use an HTML dialog with buttons to trigger some script. I've worked through all the examples I can find in the documentation and on Yagisanatode's blog. Every part of the thing works except that `google.script.run.addEgg()` isn't triggering the `addEgg()` function in Code.gs.

I'm including the relevant bits of code. I'm working on getting one button to trigger one script before building things out further.

`EggFoodTuck01()`, triggered by clicking an `ObjectOverGrid`, successfully launches the dialog

```
function EggFoodTuck01(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Decks'));
  sheet.getRange('CurrentCard').setValue(0); // Record Card Number in 'CurrentCard' Cell (0-14)
  sheet.getRange('CurrentSheet').setValue('Player 1'); // Record Sheet Name in 'CurrentSheet'
  
  // Launch dialog
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("EFTDialog");
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "What would you like to do?");
}
```

The HTML dialog displays correctly. Clicking the [+ Egg] button launches `actionAddEgg()`, because the dialog closes. For whatever reason, `addEgg()` isn't running in my Apps Script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="+ " class="share" onclick="addEgg()" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="action" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </div>
    <script>
    function addEgg(){
    google.script.run.addEgg();
    google.script.host.close();
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's `addEgg()` in the Apps Script. It's not running at all. The 'card' variable won't even log.

```
function addEgg(){
  // Get card and sheet data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Decks'));
  var card = sheet.getRange('CurrentCard').getValue();
  var sheetname = sheet.getRange('CurrentSheet').getValue();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetname));
  
  // Get current egg value and +1
  var eggCell = ['F7','M7','T7','AA7','AH7','F16','M16','T16','AA16','AH16','F25','M25','T25','AA25','AH25'];
  var egg = sheet.getRange(eggCell[card]).getValue();
  sheet.getRange(eggCell[card]).setValue(egg + 1);
}
```

Comment: Have you defined a named ranges as `CurrentCard` and `CurrentSheet`? Are you sure that the corresponding getRange are returning a Class Range object instead of `null`? What runtime are you using, the new (V8) or the old (Rhino)?

Comment: I think so, yes. If I manually run the addEgg() function from the editor after the dialog box closes without launching it, the function performs correctly, and the egg number is incremented up. It's V8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that `google.script.run` is asynchronous. This means that `google.script.host.close()` might be executed before `google.script.run.addEgg()` call be effectively executed.

One option is that you use `withSuccessHandler` to call `google.script.host.close()`

Other thing that you are missing is that `google.script.run` will be executed with default account used to sign-in into Google services. One quick solution is to share your spreadsheet with you default account.

Related

- [HTML Service Submit Form not calling google.script.run function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37783193/1595451)

Comment: I tried messing with that, but didn't really understand it. I do understand what you said might be happening, and why, so I'll go and read up on that some more. I took out the google.script.host.close() from the actionAddEgg() function, to see if the addEdd() function would run without it. I waited about 20 seconds, and then manually closed the dialog. No dice. :-(

Comment: @PatrickLollis Have you tried using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled? How about using the old runtime instead of the new?

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. ```<script>
    function actionAddEgg(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).addEgg();
    }
    </script>```

Comment: That code has errors. Have you reviewed the link that I included in my answer?

Comment: I tried code from the link ```<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" 
 onclick="google.script.run
                       .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                       .createAgenda(this.parentNode)"/>``` so that everything triggered directly from the button, rather than a script function in the HTML. I edited the code for my script to ```    <input type="button" value="Add Egg" onclick="google.script.run
                       .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                       .addEgg()"/>``` Still nothing. I will try incognito.

Comment: It worked in incognito mode! (the version with the script in the HTML)

Answer (score 0):

- You shouldn't use the same function name(`addEgg`) for both server and client script functions. Consider changing one of the  function's name.
- Use `close` in the `successHandler` as `google.script.run` is asynchronous. This is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763778/)